# Customize section style in refineryCMS

Tags: css, refinerycms

I need to add classes to section in refineryCMS: when I create a new page in refinery it generate automatically this HTML:

```
<section id="body"></section>
```

What I want is to get:

```
<section id="body" class="inner row>
```

or `<section id="body">
      <div class="inner">
        <div class=row>
        </div>
       </div>
     </section>`
Where should I modify?

Thanks in advance